# How to create proportion x width graph which contains seconds

Tags: gnuplot

i have data file which contains data every seconds . 
i want to present x width graph which each second data could be seen clearly .
what does my script right now is creating rectangle graph when all the small values are hardly seen , and the high values are sean clearly .

so now with the script im getting this image :
as you see only the high spikes are seen
[image]

but what i realy want is proportion  graph that will look like this :
[image]

this is the script im using :

```
set title filename.' CPU usage'

set xdata time
set timefmt '%H:%M:%S'
set format x '%H:%M:%S'

set xlabel 'time'
set ylabel 'CPU Usage'
set style data lines

plot filename  using 1:3 title '0.6'
pause -1
```

Comment: Although it is not very clear what you'd like to do, maybe you the solution is to use log scale: `set logscale y`

Comment: i just want to scale it on the x , where should i put it in the script ?

Comment: You need to put it before `plot` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the size of the plot when specifying the terminal. For example,

```
set term pngcairo size 800, 200
```

creates an image that is 800 pixels wide and 200 pixels high. If you want to change the aspect ratio of the plot without changing the dimension of the entire image, try something like

```
set size ratio 0.2
```

Neither of those would make the small values more visible, though; for that `set log y` would probably more appropriate as pointed out in the comments above.

Comment: Thanks well its better , the first command to resize the image didn't work 
When i set it as first line on the script it just output binary data on the screen 
the :set size ratio 0.2  is  working better but how do i resize this image ?

Comment: You specify the size of the image as part of the `set term` command. Which terminal are you using? If you are using the X terminal, you would do something like `set term x11 size 800,200`. If you are using a file-based terminal like `pngcairo` mentioned above then you have to redirect the output to a file using `set output`.

Comment: Imusing from mingw32 calling the script like this :
gnuplot -e "filename='$1'" plotcpu.plg

Comment: What is the output of `show term`? I don't use gnuplot on Windows, but presumably `set term win size 800,200` should work. The wxt terminal might also be available; try `set term wxt size 800,200`.